# Hadoop + Jackson parsing: ObjectMapper reads Object and then breaks

Tags: java, json, hadoop, jackson, recordreader

I am implementing a JSON RecordReader in Hadoop with Jackson.
By now I am testing locally with JUnit + MRUnit.
The JSON files contain one object each, that after some headers, it has a field whose value is an array of entries, each of which I want to be understood as a Record (so I need to skip those headers).

I am able to do this by advancing the FSDataInputStream up to the point of reading.
In my local testing, I do the following:

```
fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
in = fs.open(new Path(filename));
long offset = getOffset(in, "HEADER_START_HERE");       
in.seek(offset);
```

where getOffset is a function where points the InputStream where the field value starts - which works OK, if we look at `in.getPos()` value.

I am reading the first record by:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readValue (in, JsonNode.class);
```

The first record comes back fine. I can use `mapper.writeValueAsString(actualObj)` and it has read it fine, and it was valid.

Fine till here.

So I try to iterate the objects, by doing:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode actualObj = null;
do {
    actualObj = mapper.readValue (in, JsonNode.class);
    if( actualObj != null) {
        LOG.info("ELEMENT:\n" + mapper.writeValueAsString(actualObj) );
    }
} while (actualObj != null) ;
```

And it reads the first one, but then it breaks:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.BufferedFSInputStream.getPos(BufferedFSInputStream.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.getPos(FSDataInputStream.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.readChunk(ChecksumFileSystem.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readChecksumChunk(FSInputChecker.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read1(FSInputChecker.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read(FSInputChecker.java:193)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ByteSourceBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(ByteSourceBootstrapper.java:340)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ByteSourceBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceBootstrapper.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ByteSourceBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceBootstrapper.java:197)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory._createJsonParser(JsonFactory.java:503)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.createJsonParser(JsonFactory.java:365)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1158)
```

Why is this exception happening?

Does it have to do with being reading locally?

Is it needed some kind of reset or something when reusing an `ObjectMapper` or its underlying stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it around. In case it helps:

First of all, I'm using Jackson 1.x latest version.
It seems that once `JsonParser` is instantiated with an `InputStream`, it takes control over it.
So, when using `readValue()`, once it is read (internally it calls `_readMapAndClose()` which automatically closes the stream.
There is a setting that you can set to tell the `JsonParser` not to close the underlying stream. You can pass it to your `JsonFactory` like this before your create your `JsonParser`:

```
JsonFactory f = new MappingJsonFactory();
f.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, false);
```

Beware you are responsible for closing the stream (FSDataInputStream in my case). 
So, answers:

- Why is this exception happening?

Because the parser manages the stream, and closes it after readValue().

- Does it have to do with being reading locally?

No

- Is it needed some kind of reset or something when reusing an ObjectMapper or its underlying stream?

No. What you need to be aware of when using Streaming API mixed with ObjectMapper-like methods, is that sometimes the mapper/parser may take control of the underlying stream. Refer to the Javadoc of [JsonParser](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser.html) and check the documentation on each of the reading methods to meet your needs.

Comment: There is also now nice new `MappingIterator` that you can get via `ObjectReader` (constructed from `ObjectMapper`), which lets you map a sequence of values to iterate over. It simplifies things so that you will not need to use `JsonParser` but just something like `MappingIterator<JsonNode> it = mapper.readerFor(JsonNode.class).readValues(src);`